# How to match against a flags/bitmasks in Rust?

Tags: rust, bitflags

Take a typical check for bit-flags:

```
if      (v & (1 << 0)) != 0 { foo(); }
else if (v & (1 << 1)) != 0 { bar(); }
else if (v & (1 << 2)) != 0 { baz(); }
```

How would this be written as a `match` statement?

Comment: Did you mean `if v & (1 << 0) > 0` etc.?

Comment: @Dogbert, yes, updated

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use `match` when you are testing single bits.

Answer (score 13):

```
if      (v & (1 << 0)) != 0 { foo(); }
else if (v & (1 << 1)) != 0 { bar(); }
else if (v & (1 << 2)) != 0 { baz(); }
```

Such concrete code can be rewritten like this:

```
match v.trailing_zeros() {
    0 => foo(),
    1 => bar(),
    2 => baz(),
    _ => {},
}
```

Comment: That's really clever! I wrote some tests to check that this is indeed correct (and they pass): https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bcbd5fb07635e0601747abf06b8d3f57&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: Is the generated code as efficient as a bitmask check?

Answer (score 1):

As [fghj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39179635/9899381) answered, it is possible to do this:

```
match v.trailing_zeros() {
    0 => foo(),
    1 => bar(),
    2 => baz(),
    _ => {},
}
```

This would be preferable to using `if`/`else`, not only for readability, as rustc generates less assembly for the match statement than for the `if`/`else` clause: 23 lines of logic vs 9 (see [Compiler explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/69dEesM6j)). It's possible that this could differ depending on architecture, however, particularly for RISC processors

[Benchmarking](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/9b4i6o) both methods with 8 bits, they have exactly the same performance:

```
running 2 tests
test bench_if_else ... bench:          62 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test bench_match   ... bench:          61 ns/iter (+/- 2)
```